# list index out of range when extending list

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

This function takes email body as input and returns values after Application name, source and message respectively and it works fine

```
def parse_subject(line):
    info = {}
    segments = line.split(' ')

    info['time'] = segments[0]+' '+segments[1]
    for i in range(2, len(segments)):
        key = ''
        if segments[i] == 'Application name:':
            key = 'appname'
        elif segments[i] == 'Source:':
            key = 'source'
        elif segments[i] == 'Message:':
            key = 'message'
        if key != '':
            i += 1
            info[key] = segments[i]
    return info
```

For another email body format i need to extend segments format because i need to search more lines in message body so i changed info['time'] and as soon i extend segments for more than 2 i'm getting out of range errors

```
info['time'] = segments[0]+' '+segments[1]+' '+segments[2]+' '+segments[3]+' '+segments[4]+' '+segments[5]......up to segment[17]
```

maybe i'll need to extend more

and above function fails with  `list index out of range`

i changed code but same error:

also tried changing number to match number of segments but same:

```
for i in range(<number of segments>, len(segments)):
```

example of segments: lenght will vary because string after Message has different value, sometime it's URL string

**Question**

when i define lenght of the segment, let's say up to segments[17],

what i need to change in function not to throw `out of index error`

```
def parse_subject(line):
    info = {}
    segments = line.split(' ')

    info['time'] = segments[0]+' '+segments[1] + ' ' + segments[2] + ' ' + segments[3] + ' ' + segments[4] + ' ' + segments[5] + ' ' + segments[6] + ' ' + segments[7] + ' ' + segments[8] +' ' + segments[9] + ' ' + segments[10] + ' ' + segments[11] + ' '  + segments[12] +' ' + segments[13] + ' ' + segments[14] + ' ' 
+ segments[15] +' ' + segments[16] + ' ' + segments[17]

    for i in range(16, len(segments)):
        key = ''
        if segments[i] == 'name:':
            key = 'appname'
        elif segments[i] == 'Source:':
            key = 'source'
        elif segments[i] == 'Message:':
            key = 'message'
        if key != '':
            i += 1
            info[key] = segments[i]
    return info




        if mail["Subject"].find("PA1") > 0 or mail["Subject"].find("PA2") > 0:
            body = get_autosys_body(mail)

        # print(body)
        for line in body.splitlines():
            if 'Application Name' in line:
                job_info = parse_subject(line)
                break

        print(job_info)
```

I need to pass line variable (content below)

```
 name:Contoso.Service
 Source: host15
 Timestamp: 2019-01-22T00:00:43.901Z
 Message:null
```

to `parse_subject(line)` function and from above output to get:

`Contoso.Service` as value of `job_info['appname']`
`host15` as value of `jobinfo['source']`

`null` as value of `jobinfo['message']`

Comment: index, sorry just edited it

Comment: What does your input string look like?

Comment: @Pythonnoob if the length of `segment` varies, then you can't just define 'info['time']` to be equal to a sum of a particular length, you would have to vary how many elements are in the sum based on how many are actually in segment.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: already provided in second example where segment is long up to 17

Comment: @Pythonnoob I recommend reading that it is a [MCVE] so that you understand what I have asked you, and not just pieces of code without a complete context

Comment: just posted complete code

Comment: We can't run that code. You were closer originally. You just need to post the actual value of "line", preferably in python code which tests parse_subject.

Comment: just posted it, thanks

Comment: It has multiple lines, but you are splitting on space. Wouldn't you want to split on newline, then split on colon?

Comment: the issue is that this variable don't accept regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you need to debug it. The error is telling you exactly what is wrong.

```
def old_parse_subject(line):
    info = {}
    segments = line.split(' ')
    if len(segments < 18):
        raise ValueError("segments[17] won't work if segments is not that long")
```

You could have done a print(len(segments)) or just print (segments) right before where you know the error is.

For reading an email header, if you know it has multiple lines, you get those with split('\n') and then for each line if you know it is "name: value" you get that with split(':', 1).

The second argument to split says only split on 1 colon, because any additional colons are allowed to be part of the data. For example, timestamps have colons.

```
def parse_subject(headers):
    info = {}
    # split the full header into separate lines
    for line in headers.split('\n'):
        # split on colon, but only once
        key, value = line.split(':', 1)
        # store info
        info[key] = value
    return info

data = """name:Contoso.Service
Source: host15
Timestamp: 2019-01-22T00:00:43.901Z
Message:null"""

print (parse_subject(data))
```

> {'name': 'Contoso.Service', 'Source': ' host15', 'Timestamp': ' 2019-01-22T00:00:43.901Z', 'Message': 'null'}